# Django using checkbox export csv

Tags: django

I do not know how to download the files that have been  check box; please help me;

this is my views.py:

```
def export_selected_data(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        _selected_action= request.POST.getlist('_selected_action')
        _selected_action =get_object_or_404(User, pk=user_id)

    response = HttpResponse(mimetype='application/vnd.ms-excel; charset="Shift_JIS"')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=file.csv'
    writer = csv.writer(response)
    obj_all=User.objects.all()
    for obj in obj_all:
        row=[]
        for field in User._meta.fields:
            row.append(unicode(getattr(obj,field.name)).encode("cp932"))
        writer.writerow(row)
    return response
```

this is index.html:

```
        <tr>
            <td><input class="action-select" name="_selected_action" type="checkbox" value="{{ user_id }}"></td>
            <td><a href="/index/get/{{ user.id }}/">{{ user.user_name }}</a></td>
            <td>{{ user.company }}</td>
            <td>{{ user.number }}</td> 
            <td>{{ user.phone }}</td> 
        </tr>
```

Comment: it would make more sense if you were writing in Japanese. Sorry, it's hard to understand you

Answer (score 0):

Errors in your code:

- This part doesn't make any sense. It looks you're trying to get a list of users whose checkbox was ticked but then out of blue this line:

  _selected_action =get_object_or_404(User, pk=user_id)
- mimetype for csv is text/csv
- you don't actually write to response object.